# HasDiscriminator() calls error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

For the inheritance hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Event
{ }
public abstract class ProductEvent : Event
{ }
public class FirstProductEvent : ProductEvent 
{ }
public class SecondProductEvent : ProductEvent 
{ }
```

and these configurations:

```
builder.Entity<ProductEvent>()
       .HasDiscriminator<string>("productEvent_type")
       .HasValue<FirstProductEvent>("first")
       .HasValue<SecondProductEvent>("second");
```

(I want to create TPH for `ProductEvent`, not for `Event`)

I get the following error:

> A discriminator property cannot be set for the entity 'ProductEvent'
>   because it is not the root of an inheritance hierarchy.

Can I fix it?

Comment: Getting the same `InvalidOperationException` in EF Core 2.1 with a pretty much identical class configuration.